# connecting to remote database

Tags: java, database, user-interface, connection

what is the best architecture to connect to a remote mysqlserver (database) from java swing standalone client app over the internet without using middle server

Comment: i remind u that this is remote server and distributed clients  architecture

Answer (score 2):

You generally do not want to expose your database directly to the internet. IMHO you should really think about putting a (web or application) server in between. If you want to or have to, however, you should put real effort into securing it: very strong passwords, very restrictive permissions on everything, using SSL with client certificates or possibly even setting up a VPN ... Then this becomes less a question of programming than configuration and serverfault is a good place to get more information.

I found two interesting related questions on Serverfault that deal with this issue (not MySQL though):

1. [The wisdom of exposing a database server on the internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19945/the-wisdom-of-exposing-a-database-server-on-the-internet)
2. [How to expose SQL 2008 database to the world through the Internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84549/how-to-expose-sql-2008-database-to-the-world-through-the-internet)

From an architecture point of view, even with a thick client I would prefer to have a web server in between that uses SOAP or REST to provide database functionality to the client app.

Comment: when i use soap  rest do i need any middle server 
and special configuration settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect from stand alone application swings then JDBC is best suited.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC would be the best

```
try
{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://HOST/DATABASE";
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
  doTests();
  conn.close();
}
```

Here is a collection of connectionstring to use on different databases

http://devdaily.com/java/jdbc-connection-string-mysql-postgresql-sqlserver

Comment: I think he asked about best architecture and not how :)

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely want to familiarize yourself with [concurrency issues in Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), as well as constructs like the [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and SwingUtitlies.invokeLater (see link below).  Making remote calls from within the EventDispatchThread will hang your GUI and provide a very bad experience to your users.

http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29